# How to tell nginx to redirect all pages of the website to root?

Tags: redirect, configuration, nginx

I'm closing down a website and I need nginx to redirect all users to the root and not just show them the same page on all website urls.

For now I have this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /var/www/mysite;
  rewrite ^.*$ /index.html last;
}
```

However this doesn't redirect, but rather shows `index.html` content everywhere.
How do I do a redirect so that `mysite.com/somepage` would redirect to `mysite.com` which, in turn, would show index.html page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  root /var/www/mysite;
  location = / { try_files /index.html = 404;}

  location / { rewrite ^ / permanent; }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately if the root page also contains css and images, they all redirect to the html file and therefore the page shows no images, css.